# Virtual field of assiciated model in similar queries, but sometimes not build into sql query

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have two situations where two similar queries are made, and in one situation the code for a virtual field of an associated model is not generated into the sql query statement and thus not found.

In the database:
* Two master tables (`hospitals` and `hotels`)
* One referenced table `contacts`
* The master tables have various fields pointing to the contact table. For hospitals e.g. a `director_contact_id` and a `janitor_contact_id`. For hotels a `director_contact_id` and a `concierge_contact_id`.

In CakePHP
* The `Hospital` model has two belongsTo relations `DirectorContact` and `JanitorContact`
* The `Hotel` model has two belongsTo relations `DirectorContact` and `ConciergeContact`
* contacts has a virtual field `full_name`, being something like `CONCAT(…)`

In the HospitalController, whenever I need one of the contact's data bound to the Hospital data, I can do:

```
$contain = array();
…
$contain['DirectorContact'] = array('fields' => array('id','full_name'));
…
$this->Hospital->find('all', array(
    …
    'contain' => $contain,
    …
));
```

The generated sql code contains

```
CONCAT(…) AS DirectorContact__full_name
```

However, the very same does not work in the HotelController. There I also do:

```
$contain['DirectorContact'] = array('fields' => array('id','full_name'));
```

And if I

```
debug($this->Hotel->DirectorContact->virtualFields);
```

I get

```
array(
    'full_name' => 'CONCAT(…)'
)
```

But when I run the action I get an sql error saying the field `full_name` is unknown. And I can see that in the sql query that is generated the `CONCAT(…) AS DirectorContact__full_name`is missing.

In both cases the contact table is referenced more than once, there are at least to associations with different aliases. So I am not sure why CakePHP generates the correct query in one case but not in the other.

Of course the find statements are more complex, the are more contains, joins and fields than I stated here.

**Question 1**: Does anyone know what could trigger CakePHP to drop generating the code for an associated model's virtual field?

I read that the containable behavious is a bit delicate and that in some situations it is better to use joins.

So in that one case where the virtual field didn't work I used joins instead of contain. Nevertheless the virtual field is not generated, so I did it explicitly for both assiciations:

```
$fields[] = 'DirectorContact.id';
$fields[] = 'CONCAT(…) AS `DirectorContact__name_or_company`';
$fields[] = 'ConciergeContact.id';
$fields[] = 'CONCAT(…) AS `ConciergeContact__name_or_company`';
```

If I debug the result of the query:

```
array(
    'Hotel' => array(
        'id' => '123',
    ),
    'DirectorContact' => array(
        'id' => '456',
        'name_or_company' => 'Some name'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'ConciergeContact__name_or_company' => 'Some other name',
    ),
    'ConciergeContact' => array(
        'id' => '789'
    ),
)
```

So for the first association the automagic works and CakePHP write the content of the virtual field `DirectorContact__name_or_company` into the `DirectorContact` part of the associative array, but the other get's placed into the "general" part for computed fields referenced by key 0.

But what's even more interesting: if I exchange the order of the model references in the field definition to

```
$fields[] = 'ConciergeContact.id';
$fields[] = 'CONCAT(…) AS `ConciergeContact__name_or_company`';
$fields[] = 'DirectorContact.id';
$fields[] = 'CONCAT(…) AS `DirectorContact__name_or_company`';
```

the result is

```
array(
    'Hotel' => array(
        'id' => '123',
    ),
    'ConciergeContact' => array(
        'id' => '789'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'ConciergeContact__name_or_company' => 'Some other name',
        'DirectorContact__name_or_company' => 'Some name',
    ),
    'DirectorContact' => array(
        'id' => '456',
    ),
)
```

So now the automagic does not work anymore at all and both virtual fields are wqritten into the general part.

**Question 2**: Does anyone know the reason for this, and how to get CakePHP's automagic to work for all cases?

(Using version 2.4.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging into CakePHP's code I found the reason.

If you define the fields option for the query, then virtualFields will not be created (even if you add them to the fields option).

In the unit DboSource.php there is the function `read(Model $model, $queryData = array(), $recursive = null)`.

A snippet of the code of that function:

```
if (!empty($queryData['fields'])) {
    $bypass = true;
    …
} else {
    …
}
$_associations = $model->associations();
…
foreach ($_associations as $type) {
    foreach ($model->{$type} as $assoc => $assocData) {
        …
        if ($model->useDbConfig === $linkModel->useDbConfig) {
            if ($bypass) {
                $assocData['fields'] = false;
            }
            if ($this->generateAssociationQuery($model, $linkModel, $type, $assoc, $assocData, $queryData, $external, $null) === true) {
                …
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SO when the fields option is defined then a variable `$bypass` is set to true. Further down, where the query code for all associated models is built, when `$bypass` is true, the fields definitions of the associated models is set to false. This apparently also deletes the virtual fields.

And then when you include that field in the query's field option, it will not be found.

Rather logical…